# Header files are found but the content seems not to be included by the preprocessor

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth

I'm trying to build LineageOS 21.0 for my device and I've downloaded all needed source code (I'm NOT new to this job because I've successfully built LineageOS from 15 to 20 for this device).
But here I'm running into errors that I don't understand.
I'm talking about "android_packages_modules_Bluetooth" https://github.com/LineageOS-UL/android_packages_modules_Bluetooth
The error messages are like this:

```
packages/modules/Bluetooth/android/app/jni/com_android_bluetooth_BluetoothQualityReport.cpp:125:70: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BT_BQR_ID'
      (BluetoothQualityReportInterface*)btInf->get_profile_interface(BT_BQR_ID);
                                                                     ^
In file included from packages/modules/Bluetooth/android/app/jni/com_android_bluetooth_a2dp.cpp:19:
packages/modules/Bluetooth/android/app/jni/com_android_bluetooth.h:92:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FALLTHROUGH_INTENDED'
            FALLTHROUGH_INTENDED;
            ^
packages/modules/Bluetooth/android/app/jni/com_android_bluetooth.h:100:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FALLTHROUGH_INTENDED'
            FALLTHROUGH_INTENDED;
            ^
packages/modules/Bluetooth/android/app/jni/com_android_bluetooth_avrcp_target.cpp:298:48: error: no member named 'get_avrcp_service' in 'bt_interface_t'
  sServiceInterface = getBluetoothInterface()->get_avrcp_service();
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
packages/modules/Bluetooth/android/app/jni/com_android_bluetooth_btservice_ActivityAttribution.cpp:129:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BT_ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTION_ID'
          BT_ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTION_ID);
          ^
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/btif/include/btif_common.h:227:34: error: unknown type name 'bt_hci_error_code_t'
                                 bt_hci_error_code_t hci_reason,
                                 ^
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/btif/include/btif_common.h:228:34: error: unknown type name 'bt_conn_direction_t'
                                 bt_conn_direction_t direction,
                                 ^
```

Please remember, there are no error messages that points to not found header files. And the source code is origininally from Google and **should** work.
What might get wrong?

Comment: Which exact version are you building? The branch has seen updates in the past month.

Comment: I've forgotten: Lineage 21.0.

Comment: Which _commit_ in that repository are you trying to build?

Comment: I don't understand this question! I don't fetch any special commit; I'm taking the whole stuff and try to build it all inside my build environment.
`<project path="packages/modules/Bluetooth" name="LineageOS-UL/android_packages_modules_Bluetooth" remote="losul" />`

Comment: That "the whole stuff" must resolve to a commit

Comment: I would like to thank you for trying to help me, but unfortunately the tips I have received so far have not been helpful!
As I wrote, I've been building custom ROM's for a very long time and I've never had to resolve a specific commit.
Maybe I don't understand the reference to a specific commit either.

Comment: Those weren't tips. If you cannot even tell us what exact code you are trying to build (uniquely identified by commit id) nor provide an [mre] of how you are building it, I do not expect anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Here is an example on how to build a ROM: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/z3c/build/

Comment: By the term "ROM" I mean a complete Android for a specific device. Not a single app or apk.
That's what I've been doing for quite some time: building a ROM for a specific device.
This also worked well until LineageOS 20.0 (Android 13), but with LineageOS 21.0 (Android 14) the errors mentioned at the beginning appear for the first time.
I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: As somebody who has contributed (albeit minor) changes to AOSP I am very well aware of what a ROM is and how one is constructed. You cannot seriously expect random people on the internet to pull down several gigabytes of code and build tools then spend untold hours building the entire thing only to then find out that the latest commit on the branch actually works and you were building one of the other 5000+. Please figure out what commit you are on (it is literally as simple as doing `git rev-parse HEAD` in the package subdirectory) and find a build target that builds _just_ this package.

Comment: I didn't want to offend anyone. I thought that not everyone knows what I meant by "ROM".
I'm on 4a60c8c20a5081907b59482b6e20f77a634b333f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved! It needs a lot of modifications in the common device tree of our devices; beginning with this one: [link to common device tree](https://github.com/Sony-MSM8994-Dev/android_device_sony_kitakami-common/commit/bfdb128112eb1b3f7e34ad880c0bb0ace893c09d)